# The function $F$ is the inverse of the given function $f$ on the interval $(a,b)$. Find $F(t_0)$ if $f(x)= x^2-5x+6$, $(a,b)=(3,5)$, $t_0=2$.

Tags: calculus, functions

I tried to calculate the discriminant and got two answers $x_1=3, x_2=2$ but it didn’t give me anything, then I tried to get the inverse function $f(x)=x^2-5x+6$ but I couldn’t, so I ask you to help.

Comment: You only need find the inverse on $(3,5)$. Sketch $f$ in this region. Then draw it again but with the $x$ and $y$ values flipped. This is the sketch of $F$. Find its value at $2$ and you're done. To do this algebraically, you need only solve $2=x^2-5x+6$ and take the answer that lies in $(3,5)$

Comment: OK thank you very much.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y=x^2-5x+6=(x-\frac{5}{2})^2-(\frac{1}{2})^2$

Hence:

$x=\frac{5}{2} ± \sqrt{y+(\frac{1}{2})^2}$

=> This is a good start to find $F(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

Solve $x^2 - 5x +6 = 2$ or $x^2 - 5x + 4 = 0$ which gives you $x_1 = 4, x_2 = 1$ (I don't know why you get 3 and 2) and then you take the $x$ in your interval $(3,5)$ which is $x=4$